# How to retrieve kABPhoneNumber from Address Book in Cocoa with multiValues?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to extract phone numbers from an ABRecord and put it into a NSTableView. It logs the number, but the app crashes when the tableView is scrolled and tries to get more data. Is the way I'm retrieving the number the right way to do so? Its not clear to me why it sometimes fails to load it into the cell.

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{

contactCell *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

if( [tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"cell"] )
{
    ABPerson *indexedPerson = contactsArr[row];
    ABRecord *record = contactsArr[row];

    NSString *numberString = @"";

    NSString *nameInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                          [indexedPerson valueForKey:kABFirstNameProperty],
                          [indexedPerson valueForKey:kABLastNameProperty]];
    //get the number
    ABMutableMultiValue *multiValue = [record valueForProperty:kABPhoneProperty];

    NSLog(@"currentPerson: %@",indexedPerson);

    //see if there is data in the multi value
    if ([multiValue valueAtIndex:1]) {
        numberString = [multiValue valueAtIndex:1];
    } else {
        numberString = @"";
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ test", numberString);

    //set the strings
    [cellView.nameField setTitle:nameInfo];
    //set field in cell
    [cellView.numberField setTitle:numberString];

    return cellView;
}
return cellView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking index 0, I was checking index 1. Changing to index 0 in the if statement checking for data in the multivalue resolved the issue.